# stylesheets not working in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Stylesheets are not working in my rails app.
If I clear the browser cache stylesheets work.
Is there a way I don't have to clear the browser cache?

I have tried `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` but it does not work for me.

Comment: You shouldn't have to take any special actions with asset precompilation in development.

Answer (score 0):

`RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

Comment: You don't have to do this. you shouldn't have a public/assets folder in development. This way leads to frustration.